# i want to verify the sub menu links name using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to verify the sub menu links name using selenium webdriver. Can anyone, please, help me to create a function for that? Please find my source code below.

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/home.xhtml">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Business <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/agentHierarchy.xhtml">Agent Hierarchy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/bob/newBusinessSearch.xhtml">Pending New Business</a>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/bob/inforceBusinessSearch.xhtml">Book of Business</a>
                            </li> 
                            <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/commissions/commissionsDefault.xhtml">Commissions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/licenseRenewals.xhtml">License Renewals</a></li>


                            <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/bob/trialAppPolicySearch.xhtml">Trial Applications</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
```

Comment: what you have tried to create your own function?

Comment: I have tried to get the sub menu links name count using below code but its not worked 
List<WebElement> dropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@class = 'dropdown-menu']/@href"));
System.out.println(dropdown.size());

Comment: I want to verify one by one sub menu links name using webdriver can u plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed wrong xpath, try this

```
List<WebElement> dropdowns = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class = 'dropdown-menu']//a")); 
System.out.println(dropdowns.size());

for (WebElement dropdown : dropdowns) {
    System.out.println(dropdown.getText());
}
```